# Redux heavy lifting: where should I perform the download and saving to FS of multiple files?

Tags: javascript, architecture, redux, electron

I have a React+Redux application (built and distributed with electron) that once a day, at a given hour in the night, should download and save to the user's filesystem multiple files.

The API calls and the overall number of operations seem to me a bit too much to be done in the reducers, so I'm here to ask if there is a better design pattern for this.

Just to give you an idea, here's the operations I should perform to complete this task:

1. [API call] get a list of folders from the remote service
2. [API call] for each folder, get a list of contents
3. [FS]: verify if the local content is present and the same version as the remote one

   - [API call] if not, download content
   - [FS] save content to filesystem

The number of involved folders ranges from 10 to 30, and the contents could easily go up to 100 or more.

Key points:

- **The user is not using the app during this operation**, so no need for webworkers or other async black magic
- The sync could be done by an external script in another language, but I'd rather keep all the logic in a single app for ease of distribution and setup
- All the points above marked as [API call] are asynchronous in my current setup, so there's a bit of non-trivial callback management involved

Any idea on where I could put this whole bunch of code, while still keeping my code readable and maintainable? Should it be the reducer, action creator, container component, presentational component or something else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd create a [redux-saga](https://github.com/yelouafi/redux-saga) for this task. Check out the readme, it gives pretty good idea what is it. It can be quite difficult to understand at first, but in the end you get a code that is easy to read and test.

Comment: Definitely not easy to understand at first, but really helpful with this use case! Thanks for the hint, I ended up having a pretty clean and tidy code!